# mongo: drop collection using the terminal

Tags: bash, mongodb, command-line-interface

I want to import data into a couple of collections. This is what I do

```
$> mongoimport -d myDB -c myCollection --file file.json
```

The problem is that this will only work if the collection is empty, otherwise I get errors like

```
Mon Mar 31 10:45:52.696 E11000 duplicate key error index:.....
```

Because I want to do this in a bash script I need to clear/drop the collections first. How can I do this in a bash script ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Straight from the manual page, use the [`--drop`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--drop) option:

> --drop
>
> Modifies the import process so that the target instance drops every collection before importing the collection from the input.

So you can **remove** the collection you are importing into and start new.

```
mongoimport -d myDB -c myCollection --drop --file file.json
```

Answer (score 8):

Call the `db.collection.drop()` method on a collection to drop it from the database.

In bash use `mongo <dbname> --eval "db.<collectionName>.drop()"`